# Android: localized 'today' String

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I'm using `java.util.Calendar` in my app. One of my favorite features is the `getDisplayName()` method to get a localized String for the name of a month or a weekday for example.

Now I was wondering, is there a way to get the String "today" in the user's language? Thus without maintaining several `strings.xml` for different languages?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail with an example may be

Comment: I would like to call some method that returns a string with the word 'today' in the language the user has set as the system language. My question is: does such a method exist in Android (Calendar or wherever)?